# Netlogo - code adds a tick and then stops

Tags: netlogo

With this model I need the code for the first year (tick = 0) to be different to the remaining 4. I've run the code below and the first tick runs ok, it then ticks and stops - none of the tick = 1 code seems to be running.

```
globals [num_agents difference year leader_test ]
breed [tasks task]
breed [managers manager ]
tasks-own [requirement leadership matched ]
managers-own [ability wealth matched requirement task_leader]

to setup
  
   clear-all
set num_years 5
set tolerance 5
     set num_agents 100
      create-tasks num_agents   [
        set shape "box"
        set leadership one-of [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100]
        ifelse who < 50 [setxy 0 who set color blue][setxy 45 (who - 50) set color blue]

    set heading 90
  set requirement who + 100
    set matched 0
  ]   

 create-managers num_agents [
  setxy random 30 + 10 random 50
    set shape "person" set color green set heading 270
    set ability (who - num_agents + 100) 
    set wealth 0 set matched 0
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ;;first year  -different to remaining


  ifelse ticks <  1 [

  ask managers with [matched = 0]
  [show ticks
    move-to one-of tasks with [matched = 0]
     fd -1
      set requirement [requirement] of one-of tasks-on patch-ahead 1
      set task_leader [leadership] of one-of tasks-on patch-ahead 1
      set difference abs(requirement - ability)
      set matched 1
    set wealth (requirement)
        show wealth
        show task_leader
    ask tasks-on patch-ahead 1 [set matched 1 set shape "arrow"  set heading 0]
    if difference > tolerance [set color red ask tasks-on patch-ahead 1 [set shape "circle"  ] ]]
  ]


    ;   years 2 -  num_years


    [

     ask managers [

     
        if ability > (requirement + tolerance) [
       ask tasks-on patch-ahead 1 [set matched 0 set shape "box"   ]
     setxy random 30 + 10 random 50
       set shape "person" set color green set heading 270 set matched  0

        ]
  ]


      ask managers with [matched = 1]
      [ set leader_test random 100
       if ability < (requirement - tolerance) [
        if leader_test <= task_leader
        [;;leader should make correct decision and fire manager
        ask tasks-on patch-ahead 1 [set matched 0 set shape "butterfly"  ]
        setxy random 30 + 10 random 50
        set shape "person" set color green set heading 270 set matched  0]

        ]
     ]
  ]

     
      ask managers with [matched = 0]
        [move-to one-of tasks with [matched = 0]
          fd -1
         set matched 1]

      ask managers with [matched = 1][
        set requirement [requirement] of one-of tasks-on patch-ahead 1
        set task_leader [leadership] of one-of tasks-on patch-ahead 1
        set difference abs(requirement - ability)
        set wealth (wealth + requirement)
        ask tasks-on patch-ahead 1 [set matched 1 set shape "arrow"  set heading 0]
        if difference > tolerance [set color red ask tasks-on patch-ahead 1 [set shape "circle"  ]
        ]
  ]

ifelse ticks > (num_years ) [
    stop] [tick ]
```

I have had problems with ticks and stop before - there is obviously something I'm not getting.

Comment: It runs just fine for me. You are using a forever button right?

Comment: Thanks Leirs - I'm so dumb! . How do I mark this question as answered? I googled and it said to click on a check mark next to the  answer but  I can only see a flag for moderator attention.

Comment: In order to enable you to mark the question as answered, @LeirsW would need to answer in the form of an answer, rather than in the form of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per LeirsW
It runs just fine for me. You are using a forever button right?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).